# Move regex areas to next line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
WiytynXtP
54.76%
Witrn20t0t0
30.83%
Wrtinrt9t8
8.37%
Litrrtnurtrtx
3.17%
MtrtacrtS
2.60%
inrt9rtrt5/0.27%
Jul2004
```

Now I want to move all percentage values to next line using notepad++ regex.

I use following regex but not working for `inrt9rtrt5/0.27%` word

```
Find : (\d+\.\d+%)(\R)  
Replace : \1\2\2
```

**I need something like following result:**

```
WiytynXtP

54.76%
Witrn20t0t0

30.83%
Wrtinrt9t8

8.37%
Litrrtnurtrtx

3.17%
MtrtacrtS

2.60%
inrt9rtrt5/
0.27%
Jul2004
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a match only without any capture groups:

```
\d+\.\d+%\R
```

The pattern matches:

- `\d+\.\d+%` Match 1+ digits, a dot, 1+ digits and `%`
- `\R` Match any newline unicode sequence

In the replacement use a newline and the full match

```
\n$0
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/keGKQt/1)

---

If you want to prepend the same newline that is matched by `(\R)` then you can use the capture group in the replacement, followed by the whole match:

```
\d+\.\d+%(\R)
```

And replace with

```
$1$0
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/63WFGp/1)

Answer (score 2):

The question wants a line seperator (`\R`) added *before* each percentage. The replacement string in the question is `\1\2\2` which adds the line separator *after* the percentage.

Try using the replacement `\2\1\2`.

Note that the fullstop (`.`) within the RegEx text should be escaped, otherwise some non-percentages might be wrongly processed. Use `(\d+\.\d+%)(\R)`. (Try the original RegEx with an input line such as `inrt9rtrt5/0=27%`.)